# Send data from android to flutter after opening an activity in android onMethodCall()

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, dart, android-activity

I wants to pass data from android to flutter.
 I have made channel:

```
static const MethodChannel _channel =
  const MethodChannel('flutter_my_private_plugin');

static Future<String> getNewActivity() async {
try {
  var result = await _channel.invokeMethod('startNewActivity');
  String response = "";
  print(result);    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
  print(e.message);
}
```

In android side I have caught this invokeMethod and opened an activity, now I wants to return data back to flutter when I complete task from android activity.
I have used ActivityForResult but it is not helping.

Please look at this image
[image: Error image]

Answer (score 1):

their are  2 way to back result to flutter

1. first way is more easy:
   that you you put  MethodChannel.Result in global variable when you call `startNewActivity` and in activityResult use them result to back data to activity and put them null after that
2. second way is to invoke methodChannel from android back to flutter and use stream to send data to UI

for android side how this is way to get data

```kotlin
val intentResult =Intent().putExtra("key", value)
setResult(RESULT_OK, intentResult)
 finish()
```

in main view you should like this

```kotlin
 registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { resultAct ->
            if (resultAct.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
               result.success(resultAct.data?.extras.get("key"))
               result = null
// result is MethodChannel.Result
            }
        }
```

Comment: activityResult is not working,I cannot get data back using Finish().I can only use startActivity.

Comment: Thank you for your help i am having issue on registerforActivityResult.I have added ss of code.

Comment: try to implement PluginRegistry.ActivityResultListener